# JMS message not acknowledged error

Tags: java, jms

I am getting this message not acknowledged error:

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Message not delivered
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirmNonTransacted(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3295)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirm(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3644)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirmNonAuto(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:4980)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessage.acknowledge(TibjmsMessage.java:609)
```

Here is my code:

```
public processMessage(Message pMessage){
    try{
        performOperation();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        if (pMessage != null) {
            try {
                pMessage.acknowledge();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    if (pMessage.getJMSRedelivered()) {
                        log.info("Message has been redelivered");
                    } else
                        log.error(("Message has not been delivered"),e);
                } catch (JMSException e1) {
                    log.error(e1);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

public boolean performOperation(somedata){
  try{ 
    insert into database
  }
   catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
      do something
      if (pMessage != null){
         pMessage.acknowledge();
       }
   }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the JMS session? You can only do client acknowledge in non-transacted mode, so make sure session is set up like this:

```java
connection.createSession( false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Also, you're doing `message.acknowledge()` in `finally`, which means if `performOperation()` fails, you're acknowledging the message anyway, meaning the message won't be redelivered for another attempt. Consider doing something like this where upon failure of `performOperation()` the message is redelivered based on broker config:

```java
public processMessage(Message pMessage){
    try{
        performOperation();
        pMessage.acknowledge();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
     }
```

Comment: I am not sure how the JMS session is being created, I have updated the code. The APP has producers and consumers configured in the prop's.

Comment: That won't work, `pMessage` is not in scope in `processMessage()`, unless you're passing it as an argument. You should acknowledge and keep all message-related operations in processMessage().

Comment: I am passing pMessage as an argument. See to be more clear I have different conditions in performOperation method, and I am acknowledging after each condition, but for each successful message I am using the finally acknowledge.